# ggplot2() and gridExtra() - how to get uniformity between multi-plots and single plots?

Tags: r, plot

I've got five data frames, df1-df5.

I'd like to make five scatter plots, one for each data frame, using ggplot2(). I'd like four of the plots (df1p-df4p) to be grouped **together**, but the fifth one (df5p) to be **separate**.

I've managed to group df1p-df4p together. The problem's that the font and the overall look of the dfp5 plot is different from the joint df1p-df4p plots. I'd like some uniformity, so I'd like the df5p plot to be of similar size, font, and format as one of the plots in the df1p-df4p grouping.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point (df1-df5):

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=c(1.23,4.23,10.32),var2=c(1,6,18.7))
df2 <- data.frame(var3=c(3.32,5.34,18.45),var4=c(3.54,9.43,17.34))
df3 <- data.frame(var5=c(3.43,19.32,1.23),var6=c(2.32,19.12,4.23))
df4 <- data.frame(var7=c(4.54,2.23,19.32),var8=c(1.54,6.43,19.4))
df5 <- data.frame(var9=c(5.43,1.23,19.54),var10=c(1.23,8.43,19.9))
```

Current code:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

df1p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=var1, y=var2)) + geom_point(shape=2) + ggtitle("df1 plot")
df2p <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=var3, y=var4)) + geom_point(shape=2) + ggtitle("df2 plot")
df3p <- ggplot(df3, aes(x=var5, y=var6)) + geom_point(shape=2) + ggtitle("df3 plot")
df4p <- ggplot(df4, aes(x=var7, y=var8)) + geom_point(shape=2) + ggtitle("df4 plot")
df5p <- ggplot(df5, aes(x=var9, y=var10)) + geom_point(shape=2) + ggtitle("df5 plot")

df1to4p<- grid.arrange(df1p,df2p,df3p,df4p, ncol=2)
```

Comment: How are they different? All of the plots are the same (in terms of fonts and other features), except for sizing and plot size will depend on choices in how the plots are printed (device size, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of laying out the plots in a way that results in plots of similar size. I've also taken the liberty of putting your data frames and plots into lists to shorten the code:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

# List of data frames
dl = mget(paste0("df",1:5))

# List of plots
pl = lapply(names(dl), function(dat) {
  v = names(dl[[dat]])
  ggplot(dl[[dat]], aes_string(x=v[1], y=v[2])) + 
    geom_point(shape=2) + 
    ggtitle(paste(dat, "plot"))
})

png("4plots.png", 400, 400)
grid.arrange(grobs=pl[1:4], ncol=2)
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
png("5thPlot.png", 200, 200)
pl[[5]]
dev.off()
```

[image]